# Floating divs more tightly

Tags: css, css-float

I have bunch of floated divs that I want to distribute in a 2-column system.
The problem is that too much vertical space is generated in the left hand column between the boxes.

The divs are all in one big container, so it's not actually 2 columns, markup-wise.

Can someone advise me on how to maintain the tightness between the boxes and still honour the alphabetical zig-zag order?

```
<div class="tag-box">
   <div class="heading">
      <input type="checkbox" data-field="county">
      <span class="heading">Blekinge</span>
   </div>

   <div class="tag-group ui-helper-clearfix">
      <div>
         <input type="checkbox" value="23" data-field="br">
         <div class="tag">
            <div>23</div>Karlshamn</div>
         </div>
      <div>

      <input type="checkbox" value="22" data-field="br">
      <div class="tag">
         <div>22</div>Karlskrona</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you fixing height for the outer container? Share css code too..

Comment: I expect it is due to how you are using the clear property, but it is hard to tell without the css.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can get rid of the spacing is use 2 wrappers. An left and a right wrapper which each contain the tag-box's you need.

The tag-box's will be floating against each other within there parents and not create extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Here what happened is according to right column content your left column also expands. So split it into 2 different columns and place your content over there.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left-col"> .. your content goes here.. </div>
<div class="right-col"> .. your content goes here.. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will ruin the alphabetical order, unfortunately